# Type a text, push it to array and save in localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

In my code, i am typing a word and trying to push it to my array.

When i push an item, it saves but when add another one, last added item changes and only last typed item shows up in array.What is wrong with my code ?

**Why i can't push multiple items to array ?**

```
$(function() {

   var arr = [];

  $(".yourWordButton").click(function() {
    var word = $.trim($(".yourWord").val());
     word = word.split(' ').join('');
    $(".yourWord").val('');

    localStorage.setItem('word', word);

    return false;
  });

  if (localStorage.getItem('word')) {
    arr.push(localStorage.getItem('word'));
  }
  console.log(arr);

});
```

**[JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/pivuyehare/edit?html,js,output)**

After adding, hit 'Run with Js' button to see what is in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one::
    $(function() {

```
   var arr = [];

  $(".yourWordButton").click(function() {
    var word = $.trim($(".yourWord").val());
     word = word.split(' ').join('');
    $(".yourWord").val('');
    localStorage.setItem('word', word);
    if (localStorage.getItem('word')) {
            arr.push(localStorage.getItem('word'));
    }
    console.log(arr);
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the array on every click with `localStorage.setItem('word', word);` Try reading the list of words on every click into an array so you have the full list of words, push the new word, and then save the array to localStorage

```js
(function($){$(function(){
  var localStorageMock = {
     data: {},
     setItem: function(key, val){
       localStorageMock.data[key] = val;
     },
    getItem: function(key){
      return localStorageMock.data[key];
    }
  };
    
  $('#add-to-array').on('click', function(){
    var rawWords = localStorageMock.getItem('myWords'),
        myWords = JSON.parse(typeof rawWords != 'undefined' ? rawWords : '[]'),
        $newWord = $('#new-word');
    myWords.push($newWord.val());
    
    // save to localstorage
    localStorageMock.setItem('myWords', JSON.stringify(myWords));
    
    // clear the input and render the list
    $newWord.val('').focus();
    renderList();
  })
  
  var renderList = function(){
    var $list = $('#list'),
        rawWords = localStorageMock.getItem('myWords'),
        myWords = JSON.parse(typeof rawWords != 'undefined' ? rawWords : '[]');

    // emtpy list
    $list.html('');
    
    myWords.map(function(word){
      $list.append('<li>'+word+'</li>');
    });
  }
  
})})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="new-word" value="" /><button id="add-to-array">add</button>

<br/><br/><br/>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: I didn't fully understand.

Comment: Replace localStorageMock with browsers `localStorage` reference. I had to add a localStorageMock because the code snippet tool doesn't provide access to the localStorage.